# SSRS if day = Friday use dataset2

Tags: reporting-services

So I have an SSSRS REPORT with 2 data sets. If the day of the week is Friday I need to show the data in dataset 2 otherwise to use dataset 1. How can I accomplish this? is there a built in expression or function to do this???

Answer (score 0):

You can't set `DataSetName` property at runtime, but you can select the data you want to return in your dataset based on the week day.

```
IF DATENAME(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) = 'Friday'
    select categoryDS1 Category, salesDS1 Sales from tableDS1
ELSE
    select categoryDS2 Category, salesDS2 Sales from tableDS2
```

> This will work if both `SELECT` statements have the same columns name
>   and types.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a copy of both reports in the report and simply set the visibility for the one you want to show. The expression for the Visibility property for DataSet1 would be:

```
=IIf(WeekdayName(Weekday(Today)) = "Friday", True, False)
```

Swap the result for DataSet2.